# Помогите с селектором на jQuery?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Имеется элемент, к примеру так:

```
<div category="bedclothes">...</div>
```

и имеется таблица, к примеру так:

```
<table>
    <tr category="everyday">...</tr>
    <tr category="badclothes everyday">...</tr>
    <tr>...</tr>
</table>
```

Как с помощью jQuery по нажатию на div скрыть строки в таблице, у которых атрибут category не совпадает? Сам додумал так:

```
$('div [category]').click(function () {
            $('tr[category]').css("display","none");
            $('tr[category = "'+$(this).attr('category')+'"]').css("display","table-row");
        });
```

Но! Вся соль в том, что у tr может быть несколько значений в атрибуте category, через пробел, и для подобных случаев мой код не работает, помогите доработать?

Comment: атрибут category отсутствует в спецификации html и html5 используйте data-category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне пришел в голову следующий вариант 
http://jsfiddle.net/cJ8MV/15/

```
$('tr').click(function() {
if ($('table').hasClass('turned')) {
   $('tr').show();
    $('table').toggleClass('turned')
}
else {
    if ($(this).attr('category')) {
        var n = $(this).attr('category').split(" ");
        $('tr').hide();        
        for( var i = 0; i< n.length; i++) { 
           $('tr[category*="'+n[i]+'"]').show();
        }
        $('table').toggleClass('turned');
      }
    else {
        $('tr[category]').hide();
        $('table').toggleClass('turned');
    } 
}
```